# Definition of Property default value is not serialized through web services

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

Given this object:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

When I include this Data Type as a web service parameter in an `asmx` the proxy classes created in the service client does not have this default value definition, so I have to explicitly set the values to `string` properties.

The proxy class is like that:

```
private string descriptionField;
/// <remarks/>
    public string Description{
        get {
            return this.descriptionField;
        }
        set {
            this.descriptionField= value;
        }
    }
```

How can I do that properties have default values in the proxy classes?

Comment: How about using the field initializer?

Comment: You haven't defined any default values, you simply assigned some value to a property. Default values are defined using the proper attributes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Does not this sintax  `{get;set;} = string.Empty` mean: "when constructor is called set a string.empty to Description automatically"

Comment: Yes, but what does that have to do with default values? Default values are defined in the service's *XSD file*, which gets generated by the framework based on attributes. The XSD and WSDL are the service contract, *not* the implementations based on it in one language or another